# Asymptotic estimate of the number of points of variety over finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, weil-conjectures

**EDIT:** Let $X$ be a geometrically irreducible $n$-dimensional variety over finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q_0}$.  Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote any finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_{q_0}$.

> It is known (e.g. follows from the Weil conjectures) that
> $$\frac{|X(\mathbb{F}_q)|}{q^n}\to 1 \mbox{ as } q\to\infty.$$
> I am wondering if there is an elementary proof of this fact.

Answer (score 7):

You want $X$ to be *geometrically* irreducible here.

This is a [theorem of Lang and Weil](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2372655.pdf), proven well before the Weil conjectures. It relies only on Weil's proof of the Riemann hypothesis for curves.

The Riemann hypothesis for curves was given an elementary proof by [Bombieri and Stepanov](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1972-1973__15__234_0.pdf).

Combining these should give the elementary proof you seek.

Comment: Many thanks.  Fixed the missing condition.  The Lang-Weil estimate seems to be much stronger than what I asked. Also the Riemann hypothesis for curves is not very elementary for my taste.  In fact I do not have an elementary answer to my question even for the case of a curve.  Is Riemann hypothesis necessary in the latter case?

Comment: @makt For $X$ of dimension $1$, one can prove the weaker estimate by analytic number theory methods a la the usual proof of the prime number theorem over the integers (see Proposition 5.13 of Rosen's Number Theory in Function Fields). Maybe there is an analogue of the Erdős-Selberg elementary proof using Selberg's symmetry formula as well.